# Can ttk notebooks be nested?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am attempting to nest one ttk notebook within another so that I can have multiple tab levels.

Imagine an upper notebook with a tab for each food group, and within each of those foodgroup tabs, a tab for examples of foods in that group.  A tabbed hierarchy.

Is it possible with ttk notebooks?  I have not been able to find any reference or examples that deal with this question.

It seems like this code should work. I get no errors, but I can't see the second level tabs.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#import tkinter and ttk modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Make the root widget
root = Tk()

#Make the first notebook
nb1 = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb1.pack()
f0 = Frame(nb1)
f0.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

###Make the second notebook
nb2 = ttk.Notebook(f0)
nb2.pack()

#Make 1st tab
f1 = Frame(nb1)
#Add the tab to notebook 1
nb1.add(f1, text="First tab")

#Make 2nd tab
f2 = Frame(nb1)
#Add 2nd tab to notebook 1
nb1.add(f2, text="Second tab")

###Make 3rd tab
f3 = Frame(nb2)
#Add 3rd tab to notebook 2
nb2.add(f3, text="First tab")

###Make 4th tab
f4 = Frame(nb2)
#Add 4th tab to notebook 2
nb2.add(f4, text="Second tab")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

Here is the working code simplified with notation. Hopefully others will find it instructive. This example uses the model of College Program>Terms>Courses

```
#import tkinter and ttk modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Make the root widget
root = Tk()

#Make the first notebook
program = ttk.Notebook(root) #Create the program notebook
program.pack()

#Make the terms frames for the program notebook
for r in range(1,4):
    termName = 'Term'+str(r) #concatenate term name(will come from dict)
    term = Frame(program)   #create frame widget to go in program nb
    program.add(term, text=termName)# add the newly created frame widget to the program notebook
    nbName=termName+'courses'#concatenate notebook name for each iter
    nbName = ttk.Notebook(term)#Create the notebooks to go in each of the terms frames
    nbName.pack()#pack the notebook

    for a in range (1,6):
        courseName = termName+"Course"+str(a)#concatenate coursename(will come from dict)
        course = Frame(nbName) #Create a course frame for the newly created term frame for each iter
        nbName.add(course, text=courseName)#add the course frame to the new notebook 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very useful, as it requires us to compare the code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what you changed. This answer would be better if you added a short explanation.

Comment: So, as per @Bryan Oakley's remarks, I added a new post that provided a detailed explanation of the solution I found.  Since I posted it, someone hid and deleted the post.  I don't understand why.  Guys, I'm new to Stack Overflow, so how about a little help.

Comment: @Martin Pieters Can you explain why you deleted the post that explained my solution as per Bryan Oakley's request?

Comment: I didn't suggest that you add a new post. You should edit this answer to include an explanation.